# Drop trailing digits of a floating point number

Tags: java, floating-point, rounding

I have some float variables in my java program:

```
float var1=1.23456f;
float var2=2.34567f;
```

In my calculations, the number of digits after decimal point in my float variable increases and decreases to maintain precision. for e.g. after some calculations
     System.out.println(var1);
may print:

```
6.35
```

or

```
9.4500082E
```

or

```
88.25214
```

I want to round off these values to 3 decimal places and drop the subsequent decimal digits so that float gets rounded off like:

```
6.350   9.450   88.252
```

As far as i know, The NumberFormat and String.format() return the output as formatted String. How can i get the output as rounded off float to use it further in my calculations?
Can i apply a rule to my float(Float) variables(Instance) to always round-off/drop the trailing digits after 3 decimal places?

Comment: You can't express every number of a `float` or even a `double`. What would you have the program do in that case? Find the closest number that can be represented to 3dp? This would cause massive rounding error...

Comment: No, you can't get a "rounded off float."  A `float` doesn't store a decimal number.

Comment: If numbers of decimal digits are really important for your code, consider using BigDecimal instead of float. Or use an int or long representing the number of thousandths.

Comment: If you are trying to implement arithmetic with a fixed (or semi-fixed: fixed at times but changing occasionally) number of decimal digits in floating-point, then please do not. For a fixed number of digits, use fixed-point arithmetic. (The name is a **huge** clue about what it is suited for.) If you are trying to track accuracy somehow, then let the floating-point numbers float (again, the name is a clue) and track accuracy separately (or calculate bounds on it in advance).

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't get a "rounded off float."  A `float` doesn't store a decimal number.  Use `BigDecimal` if you want to do calculations using a specific number of decimal digits.

None of the other answers will get you what you actually want.

Answer (score -1):

One (not very efficient) way to do it is to still use the `NumberFormat` class to return the `String` (with 3 digits) and then use `Float.parseFloat()` to turn it back into a float.

Comment: This wouldn't work as not all numbers can be represented as a `float`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, but his question refers specifically to floats, so for his case it would work.

Comment: No, this wouldn't work.  Floats don't have numbers of decimal digits; they only have numbers of binary digits.

Comment: For example, 88.2519989013671875 is exactly representable as a float. 88.252 is not.

Answer (score -1):

Use a simple helper method to round on arbitrary position:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    float fl = 1.2345f;
    System.out.println(round(fl, 3));
}

public static float round(float source, int positions) {
    long multiplier = (long) Math.pow(10, positions);
    return return ((float)((int) (source * multiplier)) / multiplier);
}
```

Please be aware, that thi snippet only demonstrates the idea and is limited to ~ 18 positions due to long overflow.

Comment: i need something quick, less function calls.

Comment: JIT compiler does method inlining for you, so one method call makes no difference in Java

Comment: what about Math.pow and Math.floor()?

Comment: The same thing. Real world Java applications expirience perfomance difficulties caused by database access speed, network delays, thread stravation and other complex things. So delays caused by Math.pow() are of no real interest in terms of performance. Moreover, premature optimization, especialy low-level, is considered harmful for many reasons. But anyway, one can rewrite the snippet without Math.floor (see updated code) and Math.pow() may be removed if you have fixed precision requirement. For three digits is would simple be 'long multiplier = 1000;'