# How to set Java Double decimals with two zero.?

Tags: java

here is my code

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class TestJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        String value = df.format(250.0);
        System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(value));
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT : 250.0

I NEED IT AS 250.00 [not a String needed..need answer in double mode]**

Please help me to sort out this issue

thanks

Comment: There is no reason for you to turn it back into a double before outputting it to the console. As a double, 250.0 is equal to 250.00. The only reason to make it 250.00 is for formatting output, which will be a string.

Comment: You can't. A Double uses floating point arithmetic, which means you don't get to decide where the point is. If you want fixed point arithmetic, use BigDecimal instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drop trailing digits of a floating point number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936350/drop-trailing-digits-of-a-floating-point-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the conventional decimal representation of a real number (as you were taught in primary school) with the representation of a computer floating point type such as `double`.  They are different, and they work differently.

In the latter case, there is only one representation for 250.0 as a `double`.  It is a precise number as the binary version shows us:

```
01000000 01101111 01000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

When you convert the Strings `"250.0"` and `"250.00"` to `double`, you will get exactly the same value.

---

From a mathematical perspective, you seem to be *trying* to model the precision of a number; i.e. you expect `"250.0"` means 249.5000... to 250.49999..., and `"250.00"` to mean 249.95000... to 250.049999....

You can model the precision of a measurement (or whatever) using `double` but you need to use a pair of numbers to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The type `double` just holds the numeric value - it doesn't hold any information about the formatting of the number. The value "250" is the same as the value "250.0" or "250.00" - there's no way you can store formatting information, such as how many zeroes should be printed after the decimal point, in a `double` variable.

If you need to save this information, you'll need to keep the value as a string, or find a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double i = 250.0;
        System.out.format("Result is %.2f", i);
    }
```

**Output is**

250.00

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double i = 250.0;
    System.out.format("Result is %.2f", i);
}
```

The above method will not work;
System.out.format() accepts a String and an Object[] not String,Double.